# Configurando Firebird com PHP?

Tags: php, firebird, xampp

Estou usando o XAMPP/LAMPP com CentOS e estou tentando configurar o PHP para conectar em uma base de dados Firebird. No `php.ini` ja descomentei a linha `extension="interbase.so"` e copiei o `interbase.so` para o diretorio `/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525` mas não estou conseguindo fazer isso funcionar. Olhando nos logs no arquivo `php_error_log` tem um erro de **Não foi possível carregar a biblioteca dinamica** e não estou conseguindo encontrar os motivos desse problema para solucionar.

Como configurar o PHP para conectar o Firebird com o XAMPP/LAMPP ?

**Erros no arquivo php_error_log**

```
[22-Oct-2015 01:51:39 America/Sao_Paulo] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/interbase.so' - libfbclient.so.2: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64 in Unknown on line 0
[22-Oct-2015 01:51:44 America/Sao_Paulo] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/interbase.so' - libfbclient.so.2: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64 in Unknown on line 0
[22-Oct-2015 01:51:47 America/Sao_Paulo] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/interbase.so' - libfbclient.so.2: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64 in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: Seu php é 64bit? Porque se for a biblioteca que esta tentando carregar parece ser 32bit (ou ao contrário, não sei ao certo), então não tem como usar. Baixe o .so pra mesma versão do php. Pra saber se é 64 ou 32 basta usar `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento obrigado. Mas cansei de sofrer, acabei deixando o XAMPP e instalando tudo usando o `yum` do CentOS e agora esta 100%...obrigado.

Comment: Sim, muitas distribuições linux oferencem suporte pra instalação do PHP via repositórios, o que ao meu ver é muito melhor, o Xampp tem várias coisa legais, mas pro desenvolvimento eu acho difícil usar metade delas.